# Where to place PDCurses for use with UniCurses

Tags: python, pdcurses, unicurses

I want to use UniCurses on Windows. For this, I downloaded various ZIP-archives. I downloaded `pdc34dll.zip`, `pdc34dlls.zip`, `pdc34dllu.zip`, `pdc34dllw.zip` and `pdcurses34.zip`. The last was just the source.

I tried to place the files within the `pdc34dll`-folder, extracted from `pdc34dll.zip`, to the main directory of the Python 3.5.2 installation folder, to the directory where Unicurses is installed (`C:\programming\python\352.lib.site-packages\unicurses`) and in the System32-directory (`C:\windows\system32`).

But I still get the message that `pdcurses.dll` cannot be found.

What do I wrong and what should I do to solve this problem properly?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is impossible, because it was a build for Python 3.4!